# List Manipulation Via Conditionals

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I'm trying to convert one list to another by applying a condition on the list's elements. But I can't figure out how to do this in mathematica's language. Python example below

```
l1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = []
for i in l1:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        l2.append(i)
    else:
        l2.append(0)
```

Comment: `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4} // Select[Mod[#, 2] == 0 &]  (* {0, 2, 4} *)`

Comment: @alancalvitti this way you miss appending zeros

Comment: @funnypony, thanks. {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} // Map[If[Mod[#, 2] == 0, #, 0] &]

Comment: @alancalvitti that's nice! you can also freely remove Map, which seems unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific condition in OP's example, you can also use

```
f = (1 - Mod[#, 2]) #  &;
f@l1
(* {0, 0, 2, 0, 4} *)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Table[If[Mod[l, 2] == 0, l, 0], {l, 0, 4}]
```

or

```
Table[If[Mod[l1[[i]], 2] == 0, l1[[i]], 0], {i, Length@l1}]
```

for arbitrary list l1

Comment: What about `Table[If[Mod[l, 2] == 0, l, 0], {l, l1}]` for arbitrary `l1`? Remember that you can simply iterate through `l1` with this, when you don't need the index of the current element.

Comment: @halirutan very nice! thanks! Didn't know that..

Answer (score -1):

```
Piecewise[{{#,Mod[#,2]==0},{0,True}},#]&/@ l1
```

Comment: Why is your `Piecewise` so complicated? You only need one condition which is `Mod[#,2]==0`. If this is not satisfied, that you can use the default value. So either `Piecewise[{{#, Mod[#, 2] == 0}}, 0] &` or even shorter `Piecewise[{{#, Mod[#, 2] == 0}}] &` should be enough.

Answer (score -1):

(Assuming you work only with integers in the list)

```
 l1={0,1,2,3,4}
```

and then

```
 l2=l1 /. {x_?OddQ -> 0}
```

Comment: This is wrong. If you have sublists this will do all sorts of unpredictable stuff. Consider using `Replace[list, rules, {1}]`

Comment: @Carlo I don't claim that to be a universal solution. I just claim that it works for the list that Erik asks about... Thanks for your clarification, though.